# How to sort UltraTree Nodes

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultratree

I have a ultratree build like this :

- Firm

  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
- Firm

  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
- Person

  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
- Project

  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category
- Person

  - Sub-Category
  - Sub-Category

Now I would like to sort the First level on : Category (Firm, Person, Project) and on Text (The values of these category's).

I only managed to sort on 1 of the 2 values (Category OR Text) with this line of code : `UltraTree.Nodes.ColumnSetResolved.Columns("Text").SortType = SortType.Ascending`

But how is it possible to sort on 2 values at the same time?

Comment: What if you sort everything before building the tree? I think it would be easier.

Comment: That's no option.
The tree itself if being build when the user is adding firms, projects and persons. So I have a button that will sort the tree when clicked.

You have a point to sort it when adding new nodes. But the fact is that the user must be able to drag and drop nodes to different locations and be able to sort it. (First per category and Second Alphabetical)